# How do I take a list of strings and return a list of pairs?

Tags: python

[’A:2’,’B:2’,’C:2’,’D:1’]

How do you get rid of the colon and replace it with the comma? So, how do you get the above code and make it look like the one below?

[(’A’, 2), (’B’, 2), (’C’, 2), (’D’, 1)]

Comment: Please use `'`, not backticks.

Answer (score 2):

Using a list comprehension:

```
[(y[0], int(y[1])) for y in [x.split(':') for x in ['A:2', 'B:2', 'C:2', 'D:1']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Split each of the strings in the list on `:`:

```
>>> L = ['A:2','B:2','C:2','D:1']
>>> [tuple(x.split(':')) for x in L]
[('A', '2'), ('B', '2'), ('C', '2'), ('D', '1')]
```

Comment: The desired output looks like a list of tuples containing a string and a number not two strings. So maybe, you need to cast the second element of the tuple as int or float.

Answer (score 0):

you might want to look up map function and how split() works.
lambda allows you to craft your own function which map applies on or 'maps' to every single element of the iterable L

L = [’A:2’,’B:2’,’C:2’,’D:1’]

result = map(lambda x: tuple(x.split(':')), L)

if you wanted the values of the letters to be of type int, then:

result = map(lambda x: (x.split(':')[0], int(x.split(':')[0])), L)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> items = ['A:2', 'B:2', 'C:2', 'D:1']

>>> [(a, int(b)) for a, b in (item.split(':') for item in items)]
[('A', 2), ('B', 2), ('C', 2), ('D', 1)]
```